# why is the dual of abelian discrete group the collection of irreducible representations of $G$ on the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a discrete abelian group, and consider its dual $\hat{G}$ i.e. the set of group homomorphisms from $G$ into $\mathbb{T}$. I am a bit confused that $\hat{G}$ is the set of irreducible representations of $G$ on the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}$. Can someone supply reasoning or source that I can look at. Context: I am studying $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: Don't you rather mean *unitary* representations? If so, hint: identify $U(\Bbb C)$ (the group of unitary endomorphisms of the complex vector space $\Bbb C$).

Comment: @AnneBauval I got it by using that $\mathbb{T}$ is isomorphic to the unitary operators on $\mathbb{C}$, which are the maps $z \mapsto e^{it}z$ as $t$ varies in $\mathbb{R}$. The notes that I am reading stated about the irreducible representations, which didn't make sense to me.

Comment: If a group $G$ is commutative the only irreducible unitary representations are one dimensional, i.e. they correspond to group homomorphisms into the unit circle.